# How to Update AWS::ECS::Service to Fargate launch type

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have an app currently running in ECS, and am attempting to upgrade it to use the Fargate launch type.

After updating my cloudformation template, and attempting to update the stack, I am getting an error that the service already exists.

> Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::ECS::Service' with identifier 'redacted-app-name' already exists." (RequestToken: 50118296-f55c-11eb-a6e3-b31cdb2b43da, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)

I assume that by adding either the `LaunchType` or `NetworkConfiguration` keys to my service ECS thinks this is a different service.

Any ideas on how to best move forward without having to delete the ECS service or Cloudformation Stack? I am looking for a solution with minimal downtime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sadly chancing [LaunchType](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html#cfn-ecs-service-launchtype) **requires replacement** of the services. So you will have downtime.

The only way around this is to do [blue/green](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/bluegreen-deployments-with-amazon-ecs/) type of deployment, where you deploy new service in Fargate, and perform redirection of traffic through R53 from old service to new one.

Similarly, changes to `ServiceName` require replacement.